# Symfony2 Doctrine: redefine annotation in a inheritance class from another bundle

Tags: symfony, inheritance, annotations, doctrine

i have a bundle CompanyBundle with:
a class Product with this inside

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="CompanyBundle\Entity\ProductImage", inversedBy="listProduct")
 **/
private $listProductImage;
```

and a class ProductImage having this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="CompanyBundle\Entity\Product", mappedBy="listProductImage")
 */
private $listProduct;
```

but i also extend my class Product from another ClinetBundle like that:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="ClientBundle\Entity\Repository\ClientProductRepository")
 */
class ClientProduct extends Product
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="ClientBundle\Entity\ClientProductImage", inversedBy="listProduct")
     **/
    private $listProductImage;
}
```

but when in my controller i build a ClientProduct object class and that i try to access to the ClientProductImage from it, it is giving the class from the CompanyBundle, not the ClientBundle. so, how can i do to get the ProductImage from the ClientBundle?

it is like if my /** @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="ClientBundle\Entity\ClientProductImage", inversedBy="listProduct") **/ was doing nothing :(

thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the solution.

I don't keep the useless relation defined in ClientProduct.
so i deleted the ManyToMany(targetEntity="ClientBundle\Entity\ClientProductImage"

and after that, i opened my app/config.yml and add the resolve_target_entities:

```
doctrine:
    ...
    orm:
        ...
        resolve_target_entities:
           CompanyBundle\Entity\ProductImage: ClientBundle\Entity\ClientProductImage
```

all work fine, and i don't need to change the CompanyBundle :)